# How to plot dots on the pattern in a uniform distance in a canvas

Tags: android

**What i have:** Using the below code i am able to draw a pattern(Ex: Line) in the canvas.

---

**What i am planning to do Or How to do this**: I am trying to plot dots on that pattern in a uniform distance. (Hope i am clear)

---

**ActDrawPaintImage.java**

```
public class ActDrawPaintImage extends AppCompatActivity implements ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener {

    MyView mv;
    AlertDialog dialog;
    @Bind(R.id.toolbar)
    Toolbar mToolbar;
    @Bind(R.id.btnNxtId)
    Button btnNxtId;

    private Paint       mPaint;
    private MaskFilter mEmboss;
    private MaskFilter  mBlur;
    LinearLayout canvasLayoutId;


    boolean mDotToDraw=false;


    private int BRUSHSIZE=20;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.act_draw_paint_image);
        //Bind the views
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        initToolbar();
        onClickSet();
        //ADD THE VIEW WHERE THE IMAGE IS DRAWN
        setTheCanvasView();
        //SET BRUSH PROPERTIES
        setUpBrushProperties();
        mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] { 1, 1, 1 },0.4f, 6, 3.5f);
        mBlur = new BlurMaskFilter(8, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);
    }

    private void onClickSet() {
        btnNxtId.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(mDotToDraw==false){
                    mDotToDraw=true;
                }else{
                    mDotToDraw=false;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void setTheCanvasView() {
        mv= new MyView(this);
        mv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        canvasLayoutId=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.canvasLayoutId);
        canvasLayoutId.addView(mv);
    }

    private void setUpBrushProperties() {
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(ActDrawPaintImage.this, R.color.pattern_color));
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(BRUSHSIZE);
    }


    private void initToolbar() {
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
        mToolbar.setTitleTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(ActDrawPaintImage.this, R.color.white));
    }


    public void colorChanged(int color) {
        mPaint.setColor(color);
    }

    public class MyView extends View {

        private static final float MINP = 0.25f;
        private static final float MAXP = 0.75f;
        private Bitmap  mBitmap;
        private Canvas  mCanvas;
        private Path    mPath;
        private Paint   mBitmapPaint;
        private float mX, mY;
        private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;
        Context context;
        private int width;
        private  int height;

        public MyView(Context c) {
            super(c);
            context=c;
            mPath = new Path();
            mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
            width=w;
            height=h;
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
            canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

        }


        private void touch_start(float x, float y) {

            mPath.reset();
            mPath.moveTo(x, y);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;

        }
        private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
            float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
            float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
            if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;
            }
        }
        private void touch_up() {
            mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
            // commit the path to our offscreen
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            // kill this so we don't double draw
            mPath.reset();
            mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SCREEN));
            //mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();
            //Create a pointer and log the output
            Log.d("POINTS", x + "," + y);

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    if(mDotToDraw==false){
                        touch_start(x, y);
                    }else{
                        touch_draw_circle(x, y);
                    }
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if(mDotToDraw==false){
                        touch_move(x, y);
                    }else{

                    }
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if(mDotToDraw==false){
                        touch_up();
                    }else{

                    }
                    invalidate();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }

        private void touch_draw_circle(float x, float y) {


            /*int radius;
            radius = 30;
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            mCanvas.drawPaint(paint);
            // Use Color.parseColor to define HTML colors
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
            mCanvas.drawCircle(x / 2, y / 2, radius, paint);*/
           // mPath.quadTo(x, y, x + 0.1f, y);

            /*Paint mPaint = new Paint();*/





            mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mPaint.setDither(true);
            mPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(ActDrawPaintImage.this, R.color.white));
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
            mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(BRUSHSIZE);


            mPath.addCircle(x, y, mPaint.getStrokeWidth()/4f, Path.Direction.CW);
        }

        public void clear()
        {
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,height , Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
            mPath = new Path();
            mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
            invalidate();
        }



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.draw_paint_image, menu);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        mPaint.setXfermode(null);
        mPaint.setAlpha(0xFF);

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.COLOR_MENU_ID:
                new ColorPickerDialog(this, this, mPaint.getColor()).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.EMBOSS_MENU_ID:
                if (mPaint.getMaskFilter() != mEmboss) {
                    mPaint.setMaskFilter(mEmboss);
                } else {
                    mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
                }
                return true;
            case R.id.BLUR_MENU_ID:
                if (mPaint.getMaskFilter() != mBlur) {
                    mPaint.setMaskFilter(mBlur);
                } else {
                    mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
                }
                return true;
            case R.id.ERASE_MENU_ID:
                mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
                mPaint.setAlpha(0x80);
                return true;
            case R.id.Clear:
                mv.clear();
                return true;
            case R.id.Save:
                AlertDialog.Builder editalert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActDrawPaintImage.this);
                editalert.setTitle("Please Enter the name with which you want to Save");
                final EditText input = new EditText(ActDrawPaintImage.this);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
                input.setLayoutParams(lp);
                editalert.setView(input);
                editalert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                        String name= input.getText().toString();
                        Bitmap bitmap = mv.getDrawingCache();

                        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
                        File file = new File("/sdcard/"+name+".png");
                        try
                        {
                            if(!file.exists())
                            {
                                file.createNewFile();
                            }
                            FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 10, ostream);
                            ostream.close();
                            mv.invalidate();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }finally
                        {

                            mv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }
                });

                editalert.show();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

---

### EDIT

```
public class ActDrawPaintImage extends AppCompatActivity implements ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener {

    MyView mv;
    AlertDialog dialog;
    @Bind(R.id.toolbar)
    Toolbar mToolbar;
    @Bind(R.id.btnNxtId)
    Button btnNxtId;

    private Paint       mPaint;
    private MaskFilter mEmboss;
    private MaskFilter  mBlur;
    LinearLayout canvasLayoutId;


    boolean mDotToDraw=false;


    private int BRUSHSIZE=20;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.act_draw_paint_image);
        //Bind the views
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        initToolbar();
        onClickSet();
        //ADD THE VIEW WHERE THE IMAGE IS DRAWN
        setTheCanvasView();
        //SET BRUSH PROPERTIES
        setUpBrushProperties();
        mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] { 1, 1, 1 },0.4f, 6, 3.5f);
        mBlur = new BlurMaskFilter(8, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);
    }

    private void onClickSet() {
        btnNxtId.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(mDotToDraw==false){
                    mDotToDraw=true;
                }else{
                    mDotToDraw=false;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void setTheCanvasView() {
        mv= new MyView(this);
        mv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        canvasLayoutId=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.canvasLayoutId);
        canvasLayoutId.addView(mv);
    }

    private void setUpBrushProperties() {
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(ActDrawPaintImage.this, R.color.pattern_color));
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(BRUSHSIZE);
    }


    private void initToolbar() {
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
        mToolbar.setTitleTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(ActDrawPaintImage.this, R.color.white));
    }


    public void colorChanged(int color) {
        mPaint.setColor(color);
    }

    public class MyView extends View {

        private static final float MINP = 0.25f;
        private static final float MAXP = 0.75f;
        private Bitmap  mBitmap;
        private Canvas  mCanvas;
        private Path    mPath;
        private Paint   mBitmapPaint;
        private float mX, mY;
        private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;
        Context context;
        private int width;
        private  int height;

        PathMeasure pathMeasure;

        float[] position = new float[2];
        float[] slope = new float[2]; // slope will give you the tangent of the position on the path. Not sure if you need this.


        public MyView(Context c) {
            super(c);
            context=c;
            mPath = new Path();
            mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
            pathMeasure = new PathMeasure(mPath, false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
            width=w;
            height=h;
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

        }

         @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

        drawPlotPoints(canvas); // you should be able to implement this alone. It should draw a dot at a given x/y.

        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

    }

    private void drawPlotPoints(Canvas canvas) {
        int amountOfPoints = (int)(pathMeasure.getLength() / 120f);

        for (float distance = 0; distance <= 1; distance += 1f / amountOfPoints) {
            pathMeasure.getPosTan(distance, position, slope);

            touch_draw_circle(position[0], position[1]);
        }

    }    
        private void touch_start(float x, float y) {

            mPath.reset();
            mPath.moveTo(x, y);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;

        }
        private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
            float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
            float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
            if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;
            }

            //drawPlotPoints(x,y);
        }




        private void touch_up() {
            mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
            // commit the path to our offscreen
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            // kill this so we don't double draw
            mPath.reset();
            mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SCREEN));
            //mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();
            //Create a pointer and log the output
            //Log.d("POINTS", x + "," + y);

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    if(mDotToDraw==false){
                        touch_start(x, y);
                    }else{
                        touch_draw_circle(x, y);
                    }
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if(mDotToDraw==false){
                        touch_move(x, y);
                    }else{

                    }
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if(mDotToDraw==false){
                        touch_up();
                    }else{

                    }
                    invalidate();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }

        private void touch_draw_circle(float x, float y) {


            /*int radius;
            radius = 30;
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            mCanvas.drawPaint(paint);
            // Use Color.parseColor to define HTML colors
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
            mCanvas.drawCircle(x / 2, y / 2, radius, paint);*/
           // mPath.quadTo(x, y, x + 0.1f, y);

            /*Paint mPaint = new Paint();*/





            mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mPaint.setDither(true);
            mPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(ActDrawPaintImage.this, R.color.white));
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
            mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(BRUSHSIZE);


            mPath.addCircle(x, y, mPaint.getStrokeWidth()/4f, Path.Direction.CW);
        }

        public void clear()
        {
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,height , Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
            mPath = new Path();
            mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
            invalidate();
        }



    }

}
```

### I am getting output as below:

[image]

### I am trying to get output as like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you're trying to discover certain positions on a given path, then draw dots on them where the distance between each dot should be the same.

You can achieve this using a `PathMeasure` object. Example:

```
boolean forceClose = false; //(set to true if you want to close the path or leave it open).
PathMeasure pathMeasure = new PathMeasure(path, forceClose);

float[] position = new float[2];
float[] slope = new float[2]; // slope will give you the tangent of the position on the path. Not sure if you need this.

for (float distance = 0; distance <= 1; distance += 1f / AMOUNT_OF_POINTS) {
  pathMeasure.getPosTan(distance, position, slope);
  drawDotAtPosition(position[0], position[1]); // you should be able to implement this alone. It should draw a dot at a given x/y.
}
```

The `getPosTan` method will give you the position on a given path after a certain ratio of the length has passed. This ratio is defined by `AMOUNT_OF_POINTS` which you can set to anything for a constant amount of points no matter what the length of the path is, or you could calculate it according to the length of the path:

```
// this will produce an amount of points equal to 1 point per 10 pixels along the whole path
int amountOfPoints = (int)(pathMeasure.getLength() / 10f);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Where we need to pass `x` and `y` co-ordinates in this code from onTouch event!

Comment: You should use this code in your draw method. The onTouch method creates the path, and the draw method will draw the dots at equal distances from each other on the path.

Comment: [+1] .. for input ...can you check the edit ... Is that what you are referring, I still don't completely get how to add the code. :(

Comment: Your touch_draw_circle method should not add circles to the path! You should simply use the canvas to draw a small circle at the x/y position you received in the method. Also, it would be best to call drawPlotPoints after you've called "drawPath", not before - so that the circles will appear above the path.

Answer (score 0):

I made this a while back, its not exactly my best work but it worked at the time. Maybe you can use it as a reference.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class line_graph extends View
{
    private int padding = 0;
    private int width = 0;//this is automatically
    private int height = 0;
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private String[] labels;// labels for each column
    private int[][] values;// values for each column
    private String[] labelsHeadings;// headings for each segment of data
    private float xInterval = 0;//space between x grid lines
    private float yInterval = 0;//space between y grid lines
    private int RowLineCount = 0; // amount of y grid lines
    private float scale = 1; // this is automatically set according to the screen density
    private int labelSpaceLeft = 0;// space on the left for labels
    private int labelSpaceBottom = 0;// space on the bottom for labels
    private int keySpace = 0;// space on the bottom for the key
    private Path path = new Path();// bothe these paths are used for the shaded effect on the line graph
    private Path path2 = new Path();

    public line_graph(Context context)
    {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public line_graph(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public line_graph(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        if(isInEditMode())
            return;
        scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        labelSpaceLeft = (int)(40 * scale);
        labelSpaceBottom = (int)(85 * scale);
        keySpace = (int)(40 * scale);
    }

    public void setup(String[] labels, int[][] values, String[] labelsHeadings, int padding)
    {
        this.labels = labels;
        this.values = values;
        this.padding = padding;
        this.labelsHeadings = labelsHeadings;

        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int xNew, int yNew, int xOld, int yOld){
        super.onSizeChanged(xNew, yNew, xOld, yOld);

        width = xNew;
        height = yNew;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (isInEditMode())
            return;
        try {

            paint.reset();
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setTextSize(16);
            paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.RIGHT);

            int maxValue = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
                    maxValue = Math.max(maxValue, values[i][j]);
                }
            }

            float innerWidth = width - padding * 2 - labelSpaceLeft;
            float innerHeight = height - padding * 2 - labelSpaceBottom - keySpace;

            float lx = padding;
            paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                paint.setColor(getNextColour(i));
                //calculate space for circles
                lx += 15 * scale;
                //calculate space key label
                if (labelsHeadings.length > i) {
                    lx += padding + paint.measureText(labelsHeadings[i]);
                    if (i < values.length - 1 && lx + paint.measureText(labelsHeadings[i + 1]) > width) {
                        lx = padding + labelSpaceLeft;
                        innerHeight += paint.ascent();
                    }
                }
            }
            lx = padding + labelSpaceLeft;
            float ly = innerHeight + padding*2 + labelSpaceBottom;
            paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                paint.setColor(getNextColour(i));
                //draw circles
                canvas.drawOval(new RectF(lx - 5 * scale, ly - 5 * scale, lx + 5 * scale, ly + 5 * scale), paint);
                lx += 15 * scale;
                //draw key label
                canvas.drawText(labelsHeadings[i], lx, ly - paint.ascent() / 2, paint);
                if (labelsHeadings.length > i) {
                    lx += padding + paint.measureText(labelsHeadings[i]);
                    if (i < values.length - 1 && lx + paint.measureText(labelsHeadings[i + 1]) > width) {
                        lx = padding + labelSpaceLeft;
                        ly -= paint.ascent();
                        innerHeight += paint.ascent();
                    }
                }
            }

            xInterval = innerWidth / (labels.length-1);
            RowLineCount = (int) Math.min(Math.max(innerHeight / Math.ceil(40 * scale), 2), maxValue/2);
            yInterval = innerHeight / RowLineCount;

            int currentValue = maxValue;
            float y;
            paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.RIGHT);
            for (int i = 0; i < RowLineCount+1; i++) {
                //draw left label
                y = yInterval * i + padding;
                paint.setColor(0xffaaaaaa);
                canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(currentValue), labelSpaceLeft, y - paint.ascent()/2, paint);
                currentValue = Math.max(currentValue - maxValue/RowLineCount,0);
                //draw x grid line
                paint.setColor(0xffeeeeee);
                canvas.drawLine(padding + labelSpaceLeft, y, innerWidth + padding + labelSpaceLeft, y, paint);
            }

            float x;
            for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
                //draw bottom label rotated
                x = xInterval * i + padding + labelSpaceLeft;
                if(i != labels.length) {
                    canvas.save();
                    canvas.rotate(300, x, innerHeight + padding*2 - paint.ascent()/2);
                    paint.setColor(0xffaaaaaa);
                    canvas.drawText(labels[i], x, innerHeight + padding*2 - paint.ascent()/2, paint);
                    canvas.restore();

                }
                //draw y grid line
                paint.setColor(0xffeeeeee);
                canvas.drawLine(x, padding,  x, innerHeight + padding, paint);
            }

            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                paint.setColor(getNextColour(i));

                path.rewind();
                path2.rewind();

                for (int j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++)
                {
                    x = xInterval * j + padding + labelSpaceLeft;
                    y = innerHeight + padding - (innerHeight * values[i][j] / maxValue);

                    //draw lines
                    if(j == 0) {
                        path2.moveTo(padding + labelSpaceLeft, innerHeight + padding);
                        path.moveTo(x, y);
                    }
                    else
                        path.lineTo(x,y);
                    path2.lineTo(x, y);
                    //canvas.drawLine(xOld,yOld,x,y,paint);
                    //draw circles
                    canvas.drawOval(new RectF(x - 5 * scale, y - 5 * scale, x + 5 * scale, y + 5 * scale), paint);
                }

                //draw line
                paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
                canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

                //draw shaded area
                path2.lineTo(innerWidth + padding + labelSpaceLeft, innerHeight + padding);
                paint.setARGB(20, Color.red(paint.getColor()), Color.green(paint.getColor()), Color.blue(paint.getColor()));
                paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                canvas.drawPath(path2, paint);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ignored){}
    }

//used to get the next color in the series
    public static int getNextColour(int index)
    {
        int[] colours = new int[]{0xFF4CAF50,
                0xFF9C27B0,
                0xFFF44336,
                0xFF00BCD4,
                0xFFE91E63,
                0xFF03A9F4,
                0xFFFF9800,
                //0xFFFFEB3B,//removed bright yellow
                0xFF9E9E9E,
                0xFF795548,
                0xFF8BC34A,
                0xFF607D8B,
                0xFF009688,
                0xFFFFC107,
                0xFF673AB7,
                0xFF2196F3,
                0xFFCDDC39,
                0xFF3F51B5,
                0xFFFF5722};
        return colours[index % colours.length];
    }
}
```

its used like this:

```
line_graph graph = (line_graph)findViewById(R.id.lineGraph);
graph.setup(
//labels
new String[]{"heading1","heading2","heading3","heading4","heading5","heading6","heading7"}, 
//Values
new int[][]{new int[]{1,4,8,2,5,9,12},new int[]{2,5,2,8,5,2,6},new int[]{8,2,9,23,7,1,11}},
//Series Headings
new String[]{"Series 1", "Series 2", "Series 3"},
//Padding
20);
```

xml:

```
<line_graph
    android:id="@+id/lineGraph"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

it looks like this:

[image]

And yes i do realize this could be made better and that it had poor exception handling. But its just an example.